# Will an .exe file created by PYINSTALLER on WINDOWS work on any OTHER OS?

Tags: python, operating-system, pyinstaller, exe

I have made a Cryptography App, basically with python and I have posted it in github, now I have decided to create a *.exe* file with *pyinstaller* for that, because the **Cryptography App** needs *tkinter* and *python* to work. I have created the *.exe* file with the *pyinstaller* in windows 32-bit. Now I know that it will work on Windows 64-bit also, but *WILL IT WORK ON ANY OTHER OS LIKE **LINUX** OR **MAC***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good question with a very simple answer. `.exe` is a windows file format. You will not be able to run the `.exe` on a mac simply because this type of file is not supported in MacOS

A solution, if you want to run this on Mac or Linux, would be to try running it under a Windows compatibility layer such as Wine